# JavaScript - code is not working - passing argument to function

Tags: javascript, arguments

I am trying to understand bookmark application which I found on internet,here is the link for the code https://github.com/bradtraversy/bookmarker/blob/master/js/main.js
Now in that code on **line 85** he build `button` element with `onclick` event,assign it to function `deleteBookmark()` and passed the argument `url` in it which then get recieved in `deleteBookmark()` function on **line 55** and his code works but when I tried to build similar kind of code to better understand what is happening in that application,my code does not work. I am using the code below.

```
    <div id="divArgument"></div>
    <input type="text" id="argument">
    <p id="displayArg"></p>
    <script>
    var testArg = document.getElementById('divArgument');
    var getVal = document.getElementById('argument').value;
    testArg.innerHTML = '<button onclick="sendArg(\''+getVal+'\')">Display Argument</button>';

    function sendArg(recVal){
            document.getElementById('displayArg').innerHTML = recVal;
        } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `'<button onclick="sendArg(\''+getVal+'\')">....` is executed `getVal` does not hold any value.

So put `var getVal = document.getElementById('argument').value;` inside the event handler function

```
var testArg = document.getElementById('divArgument');
testArg.innerHTML = '<button onclick="sendArg()">Display Argument</button>';

function sendArg(recVal) {
var getVal = document.getElementById('argument').value;
  document.getElementById('displayArg').innerHTML = getVal;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1vjagvrc/)

Comment: how to append value for every time some thing is typed in input field using same code